# Is there a way to take a snap shot of a uploaded file ex PDF, DOCX and save it to server as an image in PHP?

Tags: php, image, file

I have a form and that allows you to upload your resume with a pdf, docx ext.  I would like to save their ip as an image and turn their uploaded file also into an image and send the images to hr in email.

Any suggestions on how to best get this done?  All with PHP

Answer (score 2):

The PDF part is easy using PHP and [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org).

I am not aware of anything that creates images from DOCXs.

Out of interest, why would you want to send HR the images rather than the original documents?

Comment: It's not I that wants to do it this way.  I'm still a jr and pretty much just do what upper management wants.  I think its for security since hr still thinks IE is amazing but not sure.

Comment: This ImageMagick looks pretty cool but I was hoping more to use the images functions to accomplish this.  What I really need to do is learn one of these frameworks like zend.